# Codepen - boostrap and google fonts not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, codepen

Im not able to get the page to be responsive and resize correctly in codepen. Im doing this with bootstrap.
The funny thing is that it works on [my repl.it](https://replit.com/@oku12xy/Tribute-Page) project .
This is a project I have to submit using codepen , so I cant use repl.it for it.

Basically, how do I get the bootstrap library to work correctly in codepen. Im facing the same issue with google fonts too.  Codepen Project ->
[Tribute Page (codepen.io)](https://codepen.io/exotic_dev/pen/mdqbZGe)

Im using container fluid so that the page is responsive. It works on repl.it

[The code is really long and messy so I didnt send it .]

```
  <div class="container-fluid main" id="main">
```

**Please do note that the project isnt quite finished yet**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the link in the official docs, I've tried it on codepen and it might work

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

I researched the net and I found that we need to put all the stuff in the head tag over here
[codepen area for entering stuff in the head such as links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m3E7.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).